# How to access step definition variables using hooks.js

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber

Hi in the below protractor-cucumber step-definition, I can modify the step definition variable `a` from before hook:

```js
    "use strict"; 
        let { Given, Before } = require('cucumber');        
        let a=10;
       
        Before(async function (scenario) {
          a=12;  
        });        
        
        Given('I navigates to google', async () => {
          console.log(a)
        });
```

But if I declare before hook in a different file say, hook.js:

```js
    'use strict';
    
    var { After, Before } = require('cucumber');
    
    Before(async function (scenario) {
        let a=12;  
      });
```

and call it from spec in protractor config:

```js
    cucumberOpts: {
        require: ['./testsuites/test1.js','./commons/hooks.js'],
```

The step definition variable a is not getting affected, as the scope of 'a' in hook is local:

**Is there a way to change the step definition variables from hook.js without needing to declare the variable as global?**

**Update:**

I tried below code:

**Created world.js**

```js
    const { setWorldConstructor } = require('cucumber')
    
    
    function CustomWorld() {
      this.a=1
    }
    
    setWorldConstructor(CustomWorld)
```

**Call it from hooks.js**

```js
This prints `CustomWorld { a: 1 }`

    'use strict';
    var {  Before } = require('cucumber');
    
    Before(async function (scenario) {
        console.log("hooks")
        console.log(this)
    });
```

**Call the same from step definition:**

```js
This prints empty property `{}`

    "use strict";
    console.log("feature head")
    console.log(this)
    let { Given } = require('cucumber');
    
    Given('I navigates to google', async () => {
      console.log("Given nav")
      console.log(this)
    });
```

**Update:**

**Call the same from step definition:**

Here I removed arrow function and this prints the World object properly'

```js
    "use strict";
    console.log("feature head")
    console.log(this)
    let { Given } = require('cucumber');
    
    Given('I navigates to google', async function() {
      console.log("Given nav")
      console.log(this)
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CucumberJS you can use a `setWorldConstructor` where you can create for example a `this.context` which can we used in each steps and hooks I think.

For an example code look here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/0b2d7e468cf10ecef37749efaddd2dfbea8c7808/features/generator_step_definitions.feature

Other reads:

- Use arrow notation to use world this in hooks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840769/afterall-hook-error-this-is-not-referring-to-my-world-constructor-when-using

Comment: Hi i am able to get the world constructor in the hooks.js but not in steps . In steps if i print console.log(this) i get empty property

Comment: Could you see the update question

Comment: The other read suggests you use the arrow notation in the hooks. I do not have a setup to reproduce your situation, but worst case you need to setup a global variable and clean it in the before. Personally I do not see to much issues with that.

Comment: It worked, I removed arrow function in step definition and it is working !!! thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Using World isn't thread safe, is it? What if another thread is running the same step and modifies the variable?

Comment: @RaminArabbagheri No idea, when running steps in parallel this might be an issue. Try it. I am not using CucumberJS anymore so I cannot test it for you. But maybe you could namespace an Object in this.context as a hack. e.g. create an array with an unique key for each test run to store something with the data you want to share.

Comment: Thanks @NielsvanReijmersdal - I want to use the test's unique id (testCaseStartedId), in a map object inside World, but I don't know any way of getting that ID without using Before. Might have to ditch parallel